# GROUP BY Function Issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below example:

```
SELECT name, age, location, SUM(pay)
FROM employee
GROUP BY location
```

This as expected will give me an error:

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

How can I get around this? I need to group by one maybe two columns but need to return all columns even if they're not used in the GROUP BY clause, I've looked at sub-queries to get around it but have had no luck so far.

Comment: What for are you using GROUP BY here?

Comment: Please mention the input and the desired output.

Comment: Which values do you want to return from the other columns `name, age, pay` for each grouped `location`? Please post some sample data and the desired output?

Comment: Think I got it, I was confusing myself with the way the GROUP BY function works, I have added all the fields in the select except the pay field to group by and it's working perfectly by group anything that has the same name, age, or location and returning the sum of the pay column. Thanks for all the replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to know the total pay by location, and you want to know the names and ages of employees at each location?  How about:

```
SELECT e.NAME,
       e.AGE,
       e.LOCATION,
       t.TOTAL_LOCATION_PAY
  FROM EMPLOYEE e
  INNER JOIN (SELECT LOCATION,
                     SUM(PAY) AS TOTAL_LOCATION_PAY
                FROM EMPLOYEE
                GROUP BY LOCATION) t
    ON (t.LOCATION = e.LOCATION)
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

You can use analytic functions:

```
SELECT name
, age
, location
, pay
, SUM(pay) over (partition by location order by location ) total
    FROM employee
```

So, you can return all rows even if they are not used in the grouping.

Answer (score 1):

(Group b[http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqlj32654.html] Must have an aggregate function in every column that is not in the group by clause. When you are grouping, means that you want one row per group. Distinct values of the columns in the clause appear in the final result set.

This is because oracle can't know which of the values for the column that you don't have in the group by to retrieve. Consider this:

```
A    X
B    X

Select col1, col2 from myTable group by col2; -- incorrect
Select min(col1), col2 from myTable group by col2; -- correct
```

Why is the first incorrect? Because oracle can't know whether to retrieve A or B for the X value you have to specify it. i.e. MIN, MAX, etc.

There is an alternative to this named analytic functions that allow you to work under windows of your result set.

Now if you want total employee pay by location, and every employee you may want this.

```
SELECT name, age, location, SUM(pay) OVER(PARTITION BY location)
FROM employee
```

I believe this is better than @Bob Jarvis query as you only query the table once. Please correct me if I'm wrong. He also has employees and employee. Typo?